# Multi-Selection in Rails/Formtastic

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins, ruby-on-rails-3.2

So I have a Many to Many relationship between Record and Counties in Rails, such that when I am creating a record, the user can select multiple counties.  The problem is that there are over 100 counties to choose from.

So I'm looking for a more user friendly way to allow selection of multiple counties than what comes with formtastic's default.

I found this blog, but the plugin it references is a bit old and doesn't seem available anymore....http://diminishing.org/extending-formtastic-with-a-sprinkle-of-jquery

Anyone implement anything with Rails 3/Formtastic to tackle this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have just used Select2 in a project with Rails 3 and Formtastic and it works quite well.

Select2 supports multi-value select boxes, so if the select is declared with the multiple attribute then Select2 will automatially pick up on that. Thus, all you need is to do the following:

```
$("#multiple_select").select2();
```

More documentation here: http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/